# Create button from a prefab in a unity C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am running a foreach loop, adding a debug.log, but instead of that I want it to create a button, from a prefab I have from the rest of the game, and change the text of the button, based on what it says in the array.

My current script:

```
string webResults = www.text;
char seprator = '\t';
string[] myStringArray = webResults.Split(seprator);

foreach(string i in myStringArray)
{
    Debug.Log(i);
}
```

Thanks,
Ethan!

Comment: This community is not about someone providing you with a complete solution of your problem. First do your own research and attempt, then come back with an actual coding problem. Until now I don't see research or an attempt of solving the problem on your own. Start at [How to instantiate prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html), [GetComponentInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) and [UI.Text.text](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html) and come back if you still have trouble implementing it...

Comment: I am having trouble implementing it, I don't have a flying clue where to start. That's the code I am coming back with. Try and decode it.

Comment: You want to create some buttons in the game from a prefab and change their text to the names in `myStringArray`? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi Indeed,

Comment: Well then you should start with the links I provided anfaybe also [loops](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/loops)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `Canvas`. Your Buttons must be created as the child in it.

Now, in your code:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

....

public Canvas canvas
public Button btnPrefab;

....

string webResults = www.text;
char seprator = '\t';
string[] myStringArray = webResults.Split(seprator);

foreach(string i in myStringArray)
{
    Button newBtn = Instantiate(btnPrefab, canvas.transform, false);
    newBtn.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = // position you want...
    newBtn.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = i;
}
```

I hope it helps you.